# Using Google Chrome as bundled runtime for HTML app?

Tags: html, google-chrome

I have an HTML application that run offline, and I want to end up with a way to open the app from an exe file on Windows. I have tried Visual Studio, but the app does not run in the WebBrowser component.

I am pretty sure I have read that I can use Chrome (or some kind of Chrome version of Chrome) as a "bundled runtime", but I have a really hard time finding anything about it. Does it exist?

Using chrome as an engine (instead of "web views" based on Internet Explorer) would also make sure that the application would run nice on computers which has not updated Windows or browsers for a while.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must be thinking of CEF: the [Chromium Embedded Framework](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chromium_Embedded_Framework).

Comment: Also, today we now have electronjs.org that use Chromium.